# Woocommerce - update "in stock" status of a variation based on postmeta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a parent product that is measured in grams and variations that are different amounts of those grams. I want each variation to decrease the parent product's inventory by a set number of grams.

I have that all working right now, but the problem is I can't get a variation to appear "out of stock" when there are not enough grams in the parent product. Someone can place it in their cart and make it to checkout where it kicks it back saying there aren't enough in stock to place the order.

I've tried doing this with no success:

```php
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    //get stock multiplier from postmeta
    $multiplier = $product->get_meta( '_stock_multiplier' );

    //get current stock
    $cur_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    //if multiplier is higher than current stock, set as outofstock

    If ($multiplier > $cur_stock) {

        // Updating the stock quantity
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' );

        // Updating post term relationship
        wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, 'outofstock', 'product_visibility', true );

    }
```

I've tied the above code in various forms to the following hooks:

- 'woocommerce_product_set_stock'
- 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock'
- 'woocommerce_update_product'

I can confirm the code is doing what it's supposed to via debug output, however the out of stock status seems to be reverting to in stock immediately afterwards. I'm wondering if I'm not tying this stuff to the right hooks.